# How to use Jquery Validation plugin in asp.net button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi all i would like to use this validation plugin

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/

In this i will use `asp:button` instead of `html input` . Once after all validations done i would like to run my code if not i would like to show as per in the demo. How can i change it as per my requirement..

Can any one help me in achieving this as per my requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
     <tr>
     <td><asp:TextBox id="txb1" Cssclass="txbName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </td>
     <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="lblname" runat="server" Visible="false">Enter your firstname</asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in your `javascript` file

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var name = $('.txbName').val();
     if(name == null || name == "")
     {
           $('.lblname').show();
     }

 });
```

this will be similar to what is in that plugin, since you using `asp.net` it is better to do valication based on classes rather than doing it based on ID values